# Шифрование с открытым ключом. Оптимизация.

Tags: php, шифрование, mysql

Делаю что-то типа keyring на PHP. Уже смешно, знаю.
Одна из особенностей - распределенный доступ к базе паролей, используя ассиметричное шифрование. Все бы хорошо, но на PHP El-Gamal и RSA работают достаточно медленно, если использовать приемлемую длину ключа (была даже статья на Хабре).
В связи с этим вопрос: возможно ли в принципе реализовать функционал, описанный ниже, на PHP или заплакать и пойти написать свою библиотеку на C?

Есть, допустим, некоторый ресурс. Скажем, FTP.
Есть несколько пользователей, каждый из которых имеет свой логин и пароль.
Есть администратор, который должен иметь возможность выдать зашифрованный пароль любому пользователю.
В случае утечки информации из базы данных нецелесообразно пытаться взломать пароли.
Секретный ключ пользователя генерится и шифруется симметричным шифрованием паролем пользователя.
Открытый ключ - для шифрования - хранится свободно.

Повторю еще раз: как это реализовать в лоб я знаю. И алгоритмы мне писать не надо. =) Вопрос состоит в том: можно ли это оптимизировать обходными методами, скажем, как-то по-хитрому использовать распределенный ключ.

P.S. Мне НЕ нужна авторизация на сайте. Там все решается при помощи хеширования пароля с солью и по этому делу куча туториалов. Мне нужна система хранения внешних паролей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать переплетение логина, его пароля и открытого ключа. И после шифрование этого месива. Из которых переменные логин и пароль, в этом будет уникальность ключа.

Comment: Решение имеющее право на существование, не слишком ясное. 
Например, как оно избавит меня от мучительной генерации сверхтяжелого секретного ключа? (500бит на PHP генерится весьма нешустро)
Если криптостойкость повышается тем, что злоумышленник не знает о способе создания переплетения, решение не подходит: как только он узнает метод, он взломает остальное. (В случае утечки секретного ключа, например, он взломает только один аккаунт.)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM вместо MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM как источник случайных чисел для генерации ключа, это реально быстрее. Вот хорошее объяснение http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/191/device-dev-random-vs-urandom/

Comment: "Попробуйте использовать MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`" НЕЕТ. В качестве рандома можно использовать только чистый рандом либо спец алоритмы(на основе чистого рандома). Свой костыль ломанут и будет атата